# Visual Studio Add Reference - UAC path

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have read the following webpage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817675.aspx and I am interested in the section: 'Use File References Only Where Necessary'

The section seems to suggest that you can add a reference to a DLL on a server.  I have version 11 of Oracle.DataAccess on my development PC and version 10 on the live server.  It is a pain to deploy the application.

The web page says that a project file should contain a 'References' node, but when I right click on a project file and open with TextPad, there is only an ItemGroup (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) node.  Therefore I have two questions:

```
1) Where can I find the References node as stated on the webpage?
2) Is it possible to reference an assembly using the UAC path instead of a local path?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referenced projects is placed in ItemGroup starting from MSBuild 2.0 first link is outdated it from Visual Studion .NET times .NET 1.0/1.1.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <Private>True</Private>
        <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

For the second question I think yes if you mean UNC path.